# Document Browser in MultiModel Environement Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-bim360

In a multi model viewer the document browser shows only a single model's sheets and views.

```
extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser']
```

Is it possible to load all the sheets of multiple models at a time.

Thanks
Bimal

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "document browser extension" was written before multi-model was supported.

Ideally, if you load multiple Autocad files in the forge-viewer, you would like to see all of the layers in the document browser extension.

Is that right?

If so, I can make a request to the team, to improve the extension, just reply and let me know.

Alternatively, if you want, you could probably code your own, with a custom Property Panel and references to the original extension:

Here's the original code for the Document Browser extension:
https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/extensions/DocumentBrowser/DocumentBrowser.js

Here's a blog post on how to code a custom property panel with your own properties (or layer information):
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/panel

Let me know. Best

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are trying to load Revit files and its 2d sheets.i will try to make a custom panel