# Changing Document of DocumentBrowser in MultiModel Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

As mentioned in [#66558323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558323/document-browser-in-multimodel-environement-autodesk-forge), currently DocumentBrowser does not support multi-model scenarios.
Is there any way to change the document used to create the DocumentBrowser tree?

In my multi-model scenario, I need to show a document tree of non-default model (for example `NOP_VIEWER.getAllModels()[1]`) by DocumentBrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, no.
This is a feature request in the backlog.